# Using Volley to Make A post request to the server Which returns a Session cookie, using cookie manager at the moment

Tags: android, session, cookies, sharedpreferences, android-volley

> Using Cookie manager at the moment but would want a want a way  to acess the cookie from response and add it to shared preferences

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();

```
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AcceptOTP.this);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String url = "<API URL>";
                String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    json.put("phoneNumber", getIntent().getStringExtra("phone"));
                    json.put("otp", otp1.getText().toString());
                    json.put("fcmToken", token);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

> Not able To Maintain session When the app is killed

```
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                               Log.d("Loggedin  Response=============>>>> : ",""+response.toString());

                                Intent intent = new Intent(AcceptOTP.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("from", "login");
                                intent.putExtra("phone",getIntent().getStringExtra("phone"));
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       Log.d("Error : ",""+error);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Try after sometime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                jsonObjectRequest.setTag("VACTIVITY");

                queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

            }
        });
```

Comment: You got a question, I got an answer. Could you please tell us, if my supposed answer has worked for you? If so, mark it as accepted, if not, tell us why not. This is how this site works, so others would not put effort in solving an already solved problem

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a lib that does what you want right out of the box. Check it out here:
[PersistentCookieStore](https://gist.github.com/lezorich/8f3f3a54f07515881581)

I haven't tested it but it looks good and modifiable